# Why is Entity Framework generating an invalid DbContext class in my .NET Core class library?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, mysql-connector

I'm trying to get Entity Framework Core setup inside an empty .NET 5 library.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I've run the EF scaffolding tool (5.0.3) to generate my models and the DbContext with [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold):

```sh
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'server=localhost;database=techtest;user=root' MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o Model -c DbContext
```

It successfully connects to the MySql database and generates the models; however, the DbContext that is created has several errors and I'm not sure what's causing them. I haven't altered the code at all.

```
DbContext.cs(26,26): Error CS0146: Circular base type dependency involving 'DbContext' and 'DbContext' (CS0146) (TechTest.Common)
DbContext.cs(33,33): Error CS0115: 'DbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (TechTest.Common)
DbContext.cs(33,33): Error CS0115: 'DbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (TechTest.Common)
DbContext.cs(54,54): Error CS0311: The type 'TechTest.Common.Model.DbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbContextOptions<TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TechTest.Common.Model.DbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'. (CS0311) (TechTest.Common)
```

Tried using different versions of the tools and packages, including [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) but it doesn't change anything.

What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your class `DbContext`. You can't have a class with the same name as the base class. A better name would be `TechTestDbContext`:

```cs
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'server=localhost;database=techtest;user=root' MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o Model -c TechTestDbContext
```